# IP based and FQDN based certificate on same LDAP node

Tags: openldap

Currently my LDAP server is having self signed FQDN based SSL certificate .I would like to have  IP based SSL certificate for the same node.IS that feasible ?

Below certificate issued to FQDN  i.e CN=FQN.

```
TLSCACertificateFile    /etc/ssl/CAldap.pem
TLSCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/ldap.pem
TLSCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/ldap.pem
```

Comment: Will your Ip-based cert also be self-signed? A certificate can cover multiple IPs/DNS names/mail addresses at the same time, the phrase to look for is "Subject Alternate Names".

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz  Yes.Both are self signed certificate.Any SSL document to create this kind of certificate?